# Render Form Data to the Same Page

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

The form works. The input is displayed on the rule. But the template displays a blank page. Help!

views.py

```
class StandingsView(FormView):
    form_class = SelectTeam
    template_name = 'teamsports/standings.html'
    model = Teams
    success_url = None

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form=SelectTeam
        data = self.request.GET.get('team_name')
        team = Teams.objects.filter(team_name__icontains=data).values()
        return render(self.request, 'teamsports/standings.html', {'team': team})
```

template.html

```
{% extends 'teamsports/base.html' %}

    {% block content %}
    <h1>Pick your team, chump</h1>

<form form_name = SelectTeam action="" method="GET">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    {{ form.errors }}
</form>    

<h1> {{ team }} </h1>
    {% for team in Teams %}
        <h1>{{ team.team_name }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

UPDATE from settings.py - My base and home templates expand although I don't pass any variables.

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        '/home/mrsaltz/thepub/teamsports/templates/teamsports',
        ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: i just try to iterate your situation in my environment  and everything works. I mean i have form and models in my template. Maybe something wrong with naming of your template?

Comment: Thank you! Template is in the same directory as base.html. Could it be my urls?     

    url(r'^standings/$', views.StandingsView.as_view(), {'team':'team'}, name='standings'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just try to iterate your situation in my environment and everything works. I mean i have form and models in my template. Maybe something wrong with naming of your template.

You have already dictionary {'team:team'} in your view. So your view should looks like this:

```
url(r'^standings/$', views.StandingsView.as_view()),
```

Your template thread should looks like that:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {                                                                                                   
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',                                   
        'DIRS': [
                        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),                                            
                ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {                                                                                    
            'context_processors': [                                                                     
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',                                             
                'django.template.context_processors.request',                                           
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',                                          
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',                                  
            ],                                                                                          
        },
    },          
]
```

Then it root of your project you have to have `template` folder.
In `template` folder you have to have `base.html` file that looks something like this:

```
<body>
   {% block main %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

Then in template folder create folder that calls same as your app in your case as i understan its `teamsports`, then your `standings.html` file should looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main %}
    <h1>Pick your team, chump</h1>

<form form_name = SelectTeam action="" method="GET">
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    {{ form.errors }}
</form>    

<h1> {{ team }} </h1>
    {% for team in Teams %}
        <h1>{{ team.team_name }}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

**Pay attention** that if you have `{% block main %}{% endblock %}` in `base.html` same tags should be in the `standings.html`.

Comment: Updated my URLs, still the same problem. I get the form, I can submit, I see the data in my browser, but nothing else is rendered.

Comment: Is it only one template where you have the problem. If it is the only template show your `TEMPLATES` thread in settings file

Comment: Just to clarify - my file-tree is /home/me/project/teamsports/templates/teampsorts/tempates. I moved my base.html to the the first templates folder. I then had to adjust my standings.html. 


The base.html renders great, and the form works fine. I still can't figure out why "team" isn't passed from the view to the template. Thank you again

Comment: if you moved base.html in to first template, then you have to change template directory same as in my answer. then create in first template directory create folder  `teamsports`, with file `standings.html` (same as in your view). then you have to paste the code in  `standings.htm` same as in my answer

Comment: Did it. Both forms render (I see my base Heading and the form, plus the "Team" heading), but no variables on submit. Dang, sorry

Comment: If you want to see the variables after submitting form you have to create new question, cause its another question. If i answer on your base question mark it as answered

Comment: as i understand you want to find and show the team, after user enter the name of it in the form. but i think it is better to use `POST` method instead of `GET`.

Comment: Why is that? I'm not making changes to the database, so I figured GET is the way to go

Comment: Close this post and formulate new question if something wrong